# Error handling in expect scripts

Tags: exception, expect

I am reproducing a minimal working example of my script. It works fine most of the times, up to many days, until it encounters a host that for some reason refuses the connection. In such a case, the script stops. I want the script to ignore any such event and continue to the next host in the list. Any ideas how to handle such errors in an expect script?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 

set timeout 5

# The script runs forever. 
while {1} {

# There is a long list of IPs, keeping only two for simplicity. 

        set servers [list 172.22.29.254 172.22.2.125 ]
        foreach server $servers {

# Creates a file depending on time and IP.

        set fh [exec date +%Y-%m-%d--%H:%M:%S_$server]

# Telnets a remote host

        spawn telnet $server

        expect Password:
        exp_send "password\r"

# Copies whatever is there. 

        expect ".*"
        expect -re ".*\r"

# Opens the above created file and writes there. 

        set file [open $fh w]
        puts $file  $expect_out(buffer)\n
        close $file

# Connection is now closed. 

        exp_close
        exp_wait
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in front of all your comments?

Comment: Please show what happens when the connection is refused. You'll need to match on the error message text.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I had wrongly noticed that # was not being treated as is, rather it was enlarging the text in the post. That is what I was thinking but was wondering if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: When editing a question/answer, click the orange `?` to get help.

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite it in Python? Python has exceptions and exception handling that makes that easier.

Comment: Oh, exception handling? In that case, why not rewrite it in C++, or Java? (Or, perhaps, you could make use of the fact that Expect is already designed to handle this sort of thing, you know.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're doing no error checking whatsoever. You're using the `expect` command in a completely linear manner: wait for a pattern, send the next message. However, this doesn't work so well when there are more than once possible pattern to handle at any given step.

Fortunately, the `expect` command allows you to specify a set of patterns all at once, with actions to take for each one.

For example:

```
foreach server $servers {
    set fh [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%d--%H:%M:%S_$server"]
    spawn telnet $server
    expect {
        "word:"              { send "$password\r" }
        "Connection refused" { catch {exp_close}; exp_wait; continue }
        eof                  { exp_wait; continue }
    }
    expect ".*"
    .... rest of script goes here ....
 }
```

As you can see, while I'm telling the `expect` command to look for the password prompt and respond to it with the password, I'm also telling it that if I instead receive a "Connection refused" message, to get on with life, and that if the telnet command dies for some other reason instead of asking for a password, to proceed with business as well.

Try it this way, see how it works for you.